# Как вывести на сайте таблицу в которой 300 000 строчек

Tags: php, html, ajax, table

Мне нужно вывести таблицу на html сайте. Проблема в том, что там больше 300 000 срок, и понятно, что такая таблица будет загружаться вечность. Я думаю что решение данной проблемы будет использование ajax + php с помощью которого подгружать таблицу частями (по 100 срок например).

Правильно ли  так делать? Или возможности есть другие более простые способы это сделать?

Comment: Да, ваше решение будет правильным в данном случае, но нужно не только подгружать новые строки, но и удалять из видимости старые. Проблема не в запросе на 300к строк, а в его отображении, боюсь страница просто не сможет должным образом обрабатываться. Поэтому лучше выводить партиями. Примерно вот такой модуль есть https://clusterize.js.org/ для решения вашей задачи.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно при работе с такими таблицами используется то, что называется "Virtual grid". Смысл в том, что на экране отображается небольшой кусочек грида и скроллбар.

Скроллбар посылает события (в js) типа "тут пользователь отмотал меня на 42%!". Ajax-ом посылается сообщение на сервер "Так, из 300 000 показать то, что соответствует началу 43-го процента" - и пользователю показываются записи, начиная со 126 000 (это ровно 42% от 300 000).

Пусть у пользователя на экране помещается 50 записей. Он задумчиво смотрит, потом нажимает pagedown - и ему показываются следующие 50 записей.

Если всё делать быстро - то возникает ощущение, что ты работаешь с настоящим датагридом.

Вообще, конечно, на эту идею наворчивают еще кеширование части записей на стороне клиента, бэкграундную подкачку и т.п. - но основную идею я изложил.

Такие контролы - virtual data grid - есть у основных поставщиков веб-компонентов, я знаю про Telerik'овский и DevExpress-овский. Это - из платных. Есть, наверняка, множество бесплатных, да и, зная идею, можно такой написать самому.

Успехов вам!